# How to hide the turtle in python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

How do you hide the turtle while drawing in Python 3. It is covering my work and I need to see exact corners and other things. Is it also possible to draw with it hidden? Thank you.

I have tried this command and it did nothing.
t = turtle.Turtle()
s = t.getscreen()

Answer (score 1):

You have hide the turtle with the following code.

```
# hide the turtle
turtle.hide_turtle()
```

Comment: That didn't work when I input it. I had to use hide_turtle()

Comment: I have updated my answer to help anyone else with the same issue. thank you for letting me know what worked. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using hideturtle() function. The syntax would be <turtle_object>. hideturtle()